# Redirect mail with AWS route 53 mx records

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, mx-record

I have two domains:

1. mydomain.fi using AWS Route 53 DNS
2. mydomain.com hosted on hostmonster

I am trying to set up an email address for mydomain.fi. Instead of installing a email server on EC2 or purchasing a Google Apps account my idea was to redirect mail to mydomain.fi to my other domain on hostmonster.

From hostmonster's DNS zone edit I found the records:

> **MX:**
>
> *0 @   mail.mydomain.com   14400*
>
> **TXT:**
>
> *@ v=spf1 a mx ptr include:hostmonster.com ?all    14400*

I added these to the Route 53 records of mydomain.fi

When testing by sending an email,  myname@mydomain.com gets delivered but

myname@mydomain.fi generates the error:

> *Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your
> message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain
> mydomain.fi by mail.mydomain.com. [xx.xx.xx.xx].*
>
> *The error that the other server returned was: 550 No Such User Here*

I tried changing MX settings from Local to Remote in Hostmonster's setting but this had no effect.

What additional settings are needed in Route 53 / Hostmonster to complete the task?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are already handing your mails for .com on Google Apps. In this case, you add another domain (and emails) to this without additional payment. They charge you only for inboxes and not for email ids.

See this doc on how to set this up.

[Add domains and domain aliases - Google Apps Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295?hl=en)

Comment: No I am not, the test email was just sent from my Gmail account

Comment: Though you have pointed your DNS to the mail provider, he is not considering your's as an accepted domain. You need to go to the mail provider and enable the new domain. GApps allows this free alias domains. You need to check if something like this is allowed in your provider.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I opted for a free outlook account.